# I need help identifying this screw

Tags: doors, dryer, washing-machine, laundry

Our washing machine (Logik L712WM20)  door glass broke and I’m trying to replace it. However I don’t know what this screw is.

Does anyone know what the screw is and what tool I need to remove it?

[image: logik]

Comment: It looks like a torx head screw.  They come in different sizes.

Answer (score 12):

That's a Torx head, you'll need a Torx screwdriver or drill bit for that. Hard to tell what size from your photo, maybe T25 or T30 at a guess. Easy to find at your local hardware store.

Sometimes you can turn them by wedging a regular slot screwdriver in there, but tricky if it's tight and might damage the screw or driver.

Comment: A set of Torx bits in sizes from T10-T40 (or so) is only a few bucks and well worth the investment. A set of actual screwdrivers with Torx heads is more expensive, but also worth the investment!

Comment: Also, you _might_ be able to remove the screw with a slotted screwdriver if it fit _just_ right, but there's a good chance you'll munge up the head. I'd only try that in an emergency when reusing the screw wasn't planned or of very low importance. The chances of a Philip's head driver grabbing on to that well enough to turn it are somewhere between slim and none, and Slim just left the building...

Comment: Sometimes, a hex bit will fit too [depends on the ratios]. Better chance if you already own metric & imperial.

Comment: @Tetsujin I would only rely on a hex bit as a substitute if you either will never need to use the screw again, or have literally no other option. If you’re not careful with that approach, you will end up rounding-off the internal protrusions, and then neither a hex bit nor a proper torx bit will work reliably.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn - I used to do it all the time - admittedly with the bigger stuff. I don't remember the numbers now, but like a 6mm hex would fit a T30. We used to have some fittings that used both - once I figured out it worked I don't think I ever bothered with the torx again.